# Not able to get user group claims when using Azure AD as external login alongside Identity Core(ASP.NET Core 2.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

**I am trying the following:**

- Get Azure AD user and role management to work with Identity Core.
- The aim is -> if a user logs in through Azure AD(External Login), I get the corresponding user details from AD, using the same, write logic to sync Identity with AD.

**Problem:**

When using AD as the only authentication schema to the web app without Identity, able to get more data from the AD request through claims.
(About 14 claims to work with)

However, when using AD as an external login schema with Identity, I am only able to extract at-most 4 claims from AD.

**What I have tried :**

**appsettings.json**

```
  **{
      "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "domain name",
        "TenantId": "aaaaaa-assss-assas--assa-ssss",
        "ClientId": "aaaaaa-ssssss-ddddd-dddddd",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc",
        "ClientSecret": "clientsecret of the application",
        "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"


      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
"GraphApiUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"
    }**
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityPlatformAuthentication(Configuration)
              .AddMsal(Configuration, new string[] { "User.Read", "Directory.Read.All" })
              .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
            services.AddMSGraphService(Configuration);

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

**My Result**

Claims from Azure AD *(as the only auth schema for the app)*

[image]

Users associated role in AD through Claims.*(as the only auth schema for the app)*

[image]

**With Azure Ad as an external login, I am able to get only 4 claims(not very useful data)**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**
[Github Project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups)

Comment: Please edit the Github Project link. It is not working!! @Harshith

Comment: Hi @prashanth I have updated Github Link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the probable solution Hope it helps

Scaffold the identity of external login 
Once Scaffolded there will be 2 files

- ExternalLogin.cshtml
- ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs

In ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs file there is an method named "OnGetCallbackAsync"
Under this method You can either add your own claims or get the claims present over there

```
 "var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();"
```

under info if you navigate to principal->claims you can find the claims over there where you can get groups-id for the *current user logged in*

To get the claims make sure to add below service  in startup class under configureServices method 
For the detail code of working MSAL refer the github project

```
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityPlatformAuthentication(Configuration).AddMsal(Configuration, new string[] { "User.Read", "Directory.Read.All" })
services.AddMSGraphService(Configuration);
```

instead of

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```